# Type mismatch. Required: (RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder!>?..RecyclerView.Adapter<*>?) Found: PageAdapter

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager

I'm getting an error **type mismatch** in the line `PageAdapter(supportFragmentManager)` in the code below:

```
class PatientDetailsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_patient_details)    
        viewPager.adapter = PageAdapter(supportFragmentManager) //error   
    }

}
```

Here's my `adapter.kt`

```
 class PageAdapter(fm: FragmentManager) : FragmentPagerAdapter(fm) {
    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return 4
    }

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        when(position){
            0 -> return(Fragment1())
            1 -> return(Fragment2())
            2 -> return(Fragment3())
            3 -> return(Fragment4())
        }
    }
}
```

layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.test.sample.PatientDetailsActivity">


  <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
      android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
      android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/viewPager"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Monday" />

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Tuesday" />

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Wednesday" />
  </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

  <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
      android:id="@+id/viewPager"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
      android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tabLayout" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are using **ViewPager2** in your xml layout for viewpager functionality. Since ViewPager2 doesn't work with PagerAdapter, **it does require a RecyclerView Adapter.**

Simple solution for you will be to use ViewPager instead of ViewPager2.

And if you want to use ViewPager2 you can follow article from this link for the RecyclerViewAdapter implementation.

[View Pager 2](https://www.journaldev.com/26148/android-viewpager2)

Answer (score 1):

```
Type mismatch. 
Required: (RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder!>?..RecyclerView.Adapter<*>?) 
Found: PageAdapter
```

Definitely, the `viewPager` as an `id` in the `activity_patient_details` layout is mistakenly set as an id of a `RecyclerView` and that is what the error says.

It expects a `ReyclerView.Adapter` while it finds a `PageAdapter`.

So, you need to check the id of the `ViewPager` in layout and set it to `viewPager`.

Comment: literally answered the question correctly. You attributed the right answer to the wrong user.